# How can I install package with my debian package?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, package

Hello I have create a debian package but my problem is this package needs to have a python library so I thought I have to put inside the preinst file :

```
sudo apt-get install ...
```

So I tried but when I tried I get "Could not get lock ..."

I guess I can't install in the same time my package and also the python library.

But I noticed when I did a `sudo apt-get install` sometimes I installed other packages not only the package that I install. So I think there is a solution to my problem but I don't know it.

I try to a create a bash file which install the library python then I can install the package but I have two files...

Is there a solution to install in my debian file the package and the python library ?

Thank you very much !

I precise I work on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. As is, your question is about Linux configuration, and not programming. Unfortunately, it will most likely be deemed off topic. You coule have a look at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), a dedicated Stack Exchange website for Ubuntu-related questions.

Comment: Could not get lock suggests that you have another session already installing a package

Comment: Sorry but my question is about debian package and how can I install a package in my own package this is the question !

Comment: As Aserre said, this is more for AskUbuntu. However, the answer is: you can't. The apt-get lock is taken by your package, so you can't use apt-get within apt-get-scripts. Use prerequisites for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the needed python library package name to the "Pre-Depends" in the "control" file.